# How to connect Windows 7 64-bit to shared HP LaserJet 1000 printer installed on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers, printer, hp-laserjet

I've got HP LaserJet 1000 printer installed on Windows XP. I successfully connected to the printer on Windows 7 x86. I tried the same with Windows 7 x64 but failed.

I did steps from [HP forums](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-All-in-One-Software-Drivers-e-g-Windows-8/Windows-7-and-HP-Laserjet-1000/m-p/574073/highlight/true#M18575) and those were:

- Updated drivers to the host based driver on HP LaserJet 1000
- Changed port on HP LaserJet 1000 DOS from file to USB
- On Windows 7 x64 added a printer -> local printer -> entered a port name -> chose LJ 1100 MS drivers

And this should work but it doesn't. I include screenshots from my work. Maybe I missed something.
//I can't upload images yet or posts many links

http://s952.photobucket.com/user/sdfghjkljhg/slideshow/

I'd be grateful if somebody could tell me what I did wrong. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've just done it on my other machine with W7x64 and it worked. So there's something wrong with my system configuration but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the printer and try Windows update, in most cases it will automatically install needed drivers.It worked for me on HP Deskjet 3745

Comment: FYI, HP LaserJet 1000 is not supported on Windows 7 so it won't work.

Comment: What you mean by not supporting? No direct driver to download?

Comment: There is no driver for Windows 7. People tried KONICA MINOLTA magicolor 2430DL driver and for some it works but not for me.

Comment: Actually There was no driver for HP Deskjet 3745 as well. The official driver was only for win XP. I got it working by windows update

Comment: Remembering back to my Citrix days..  What about using a generic driver like a HP LaserJet 4 or HP LaserJet 4?  if you have to choose, try to go as low as possible with PCL, like PCL4, if possible..  PCL as high as 6 maybe OK, but if memory serves, you want as low as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use windows file and print sharing.

```
From the Start menu, choose Settings→Control Panel.
Double-click the Network Connections icon.
Right-click Local Area Connection and choose Properties.
Make sure the File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks option is checked.
Click OK.
```

After that you have to go to the printer on the XP machine and turn on sharing for that printer.

On your windows 7 box you may or may not have to enable SMB 1.0 in order to share with an XP machine.

---

As a potential alternative you might want to consider a print server.  Its a small box you connect to your printer and network.  The printer server has an IP address you can print to from any computer.